# Matlab array of struct failing

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I'm trying to create an array of struct and prompt the user to fill its fields individually.

```
book =struct('name',{''}, 'author',{''}, 'pubdate',{''}, 'price',{})
nmbr=input('enter number of books');
books = repmat(book, nmbr, 1);

for i=1:nmbr
    books(i).name = input(sprintf('enter name of book #(%d)',i), 's')
    books(i).author = input(sprintf('entre author of book #(%d)',i), 's')
    books(i).pubdate = input(sprintf('enter publication date of book #(%d)',i), 's')
    books(i).price = input(sprintf('enter price of book #(%d)',i))
end
```

However, I'm missing something as I keep getting this error:

```
??? Attempt to call constructor struct with incorrect letter case.


Error in ==> struct at 1
book =struct('name',{''}, 'author',{''}, 'pubdate',{''}, 'price',{})
```

I tried declrng the struct differently

```
book =struct('name','', 'author','', 'pubdate','', 'price','')
```

But I keep getting the same error for some reason.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB is pretty verbose and clear on the errors that you get when you're programming.

Look very carefully at your error:

```
Error in ==> struct at 1
book =struct('name',{''}, 'author',{''}, 'pubdate',{''}, 'price',{})
```

`struct at 1` means that it found an error at line 1 of your file called `struct`.  You unintentionally named your file `struct.m` when `struct` is also the method to create `struct` variables.  Therefore, MATLAB is confused because there are two definitions of `struct`: Your file name as well as `struct` being part of MATLAB's native calls.

You need to **change** the name of your file and run your code again.  When I did that, your code worked for me, though there are some unnecessary output printing.   I suggest you place semi-colons at the end of each statement within your `for` loop so that it's less distracting.

---

If your file is different, then either of the following happened:

- You're putting a bad function declaration.  You may have placed a function declaration at the top of your code... something like `function struct`, or something of that nature and that's what why it's complaining
- Your workspace has a variable called `struct` somewhere and so you are trying to call this variable rather than creating a `struct`.
- You have a file called `struct` declared somewhere in your working directory or the current MATLAB path.

Also, @excaza noticed that the error is due to improper case.  You probably have a file or variable or something called `Struct` (with a capital S) somewhere and you need to remove that.

Try clearing your workspace by doing `clear all;`, then try your code again.  Also, make sure there isn't a file called `struct.m` somewhere in your working directory of MATLAB's system path.  Try doing `which struct` and see what you get in the Command Prompt.  You should see that it's built-in and it directs you to the `matlab/datatypes/struct` folder.  If not, then go to where MATLAB is pointing you to, rather than native MATLAB folder and delete that file.

Comment: Nope. My file i now saved as "books". It keep throwing that error.

Comment: Is the first line of your code `function struct`, or something of that nature?  That error is still very clear.  MATLAB **thinks** your file is called `struct`.  Try **clearing all variables** and run your code again. Do `clear all;`.

Comment: @iksimen - I just ran this code on my end and it works.  There's something you're not telling us when you created that file.  You're either putting a bad function declaration, or your workspace has a variable called `struct` somewhere, or you have a file called `struct` declared somewhere in your working directory or the current MATLAB path.  Either way, it's nothing that I can reproduce because you haven't given me everything.

Comment: @rayryeng or there's a separate file(s) in the current directory or the path named `struct`

Comment: @excaza - Yes, that too!

Comment: @rayryeng well, more likely named `Struct` since it's talking about capitalization :p

Comment: @excaza - hahaha! yes!

Comment: @iksimen - So what's up?  Did you fix your problem or are you still fighting with MATLAB?

Comment: There must be a class somewhere that's using stackoverflow as a TA. This is the third person with the exact same homework. ;)